# Can I use old admob ids for new play developer account?

Tags: google-play, admob

I've own admob account and my 3 android apps placed in my friend developer account. Unfortunately my friend's developer account was suspended and ads were disabled.
I've created my own developer account. Can I use my previously used admob account for new apps ? Requesting your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there shouldn't be any problem with this.

Comment: Thanks William for you quick reply. I noticed that, in one of my apps placed in new play store, I've used old admob id ( ad serving was stooped for that admob id when my friend's developer account was suspended). Will it cause any other problems ?

Comment: I don't believe it will. But you didn't specify why your friend developer account was suspended. If it was for ad misuse then you are likely to have problems.

Comment: Thanks William, actual cause of suspended my friend account is violation of impressionism in apps. Since this suspension is not related to admob, I guess, I could use old admob ids in new apps.